# Create new column in dataframe that begins adding values from a column starting from a row specified by a third column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I am trying to determine the latency of a variable in a data.frame that contains several positions where relevant data is listed by between a series of 'start' and 'stop' markers.

To accomplish this, I need to create a new column which begins counting at 0 at the start of every trial and tallies up in milliseconds the until either the stop of the trial or the start of the next trial (whichever is easier, I assume the latter.)

I have this:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29),  c(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 159, 190, 219), c("Start", NA_character_, NA_character_, "Stop", NA_character_, NA_character_, "Start", NA_character_))
colnames(df) <- c('Delta', 'TimeMs', 'Marker')
```

And I want to make this:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29),  c(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 159, 190, 119), c("Start", NA_character_, NA_character_, "Stop", NA_character_, NA_character_, "Start", NA_character_), c(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 159, 190, 0))
colnames(df) <- c('Delta', 'TimeMs', 'Marker', 'Latency')
```

Obviously, I would make a new column filled with automatically generated NAs:

```
df$Latency <- NA
```

Then I thought I would label in the new column 0 where the Stat position is located:

```
df$Latency [which(df$Marker == 'Start')] <- 0
```

From there I am stuck. I thought I could use the which command somehow, but my rudimentary R skills have led me to believe this method is over simplified and thus incorrect.

Thanks for the help in advance, and please ask if you need clarification!

edit: fixed example, title

edit2: fixed example

edit3: used real `NA_character_`

Comment: In your example, is `df[8,]$TimeMS` supposed to be 219 (instead of 119)??

Comment: @jlhoward Yes, thank you for pointing that out! I also editing the second df to reflect that 0 should be concurrent with the second "Start" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
df <- data.frame(Delta=c(0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29),  
                 TimeMS=c(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 159, 190, 219), 
                 Marker=c("Start", "NA", "NA", "Stop", "NA", "NA", "Start", "NA"))

df$group   <- cumsum(df$Marker=="Start" & !is.na(df$Marker))
df$Latency <- unlist(aggregate(TimeMS~group,df,function(x)cumsum(c(0,diff(x))))$TimeMS)
df[,"group"] <- NULL
df
#   Delta TimeMS Marker Latency
# 1     0      0  Start       0
# 2    32     32     NA      32
# 3    32     64     NA      64
# 4    32     96   Stop      96
# 5    32    128     NA     128
# 6    31    159     NA     159
# 7    31    190  Start       0
# 8    29    219     NA      29
```

First we add a column, `df$group` which increments by 1 every time `df$Marker=="Start"` (so, `df$group=1` for rows 1:6 and =2 for rows 7:8). Then we aggregate `TimeMS` by group using the `diff(...)` function. Applied to a vector of length n, `diff(...)` returns a vector of length n-1 containing the difference between a given row and the previous row. So we need to insert a 0 a the beginning of this vector. `aggregate(...)` returns two sets of vectors (one for `group==1`, and one for `group==2`), so we need to `unlist(...)` into a single vector before binding to `df`. The last line just removes `df$group`

Comment: When I run the first line in my real data set it returns something that looks like this:
    `df <- data.frame(Delta=c(0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29),  
                 TimeMS=c(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 159, 190, 219), 
                 Marker=c("Start", "NA", "NA", "Stop", "NA", "NA", "Start", "NA"),
                 Group=c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
                 )`  Could this be because my example uses "NA" and my real data uses automatically generated NA?

Comment: I checked the example using `NA_character_` Sure enough, it's a no go. Sorry for the rookie mistake!

Comment: See my edit. Change the `df$group <- ...` line to `df$group   <- cumsum(df$Marker=="Start" & !is.na(df$Marker))`

Comment: @jlhowrd Perfect. Thanks for helping me on my journey of learning R. Note to self to use `NA_character_` and also `!is.na` the first time from now on.

Comment: You can just use `NA` (without the quotes). R recognizes this as a special constant.